# Alignment issues and navbar is not collapsing

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am very new to learning Bootstrap, my navbar is not collapsing, furthermore, I want my three list items `Home`, `Features` and `Pricing` to be on left whereas sign up and login on the right.

I was successfully able to scale my image using CSS (id = brandimg). Please fix this issue.

My markup is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-light navbar-expand" style="background-color: #3ab3f0">
    <div class="container collapse navbar-collapse">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <span class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="https://images8.alphacoders.com/416/416969.jpg" id="brandimg">
            AnmGal
        </span>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Bootstrap 4? You're using Bootstrap 3 Navbar markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are use bootstrap 4 then try this:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light justify-content-md-center justify-content-start">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://images8.alphacoders.com/416/416969.jpg" id="brandimg">
    AnmGal</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav  mr-0">
         <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="right-menu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked. However, when I click on the button, the menu appears but it also closes instantaneously is it something that always happens?

Comment: No, it's not happen everytime.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
     <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Signup</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

However, I would recommend you to read this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/ you will learn all you need about bootstrap navbars.